# Creating unique animations with Swift and applying them to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, optimization

Apple’s Keynote application has some really interesting animations. For example, the “Build Out” animation “Vanish” is particularly interesting.

The below GIF image shows this animation played over a number of seconds with a shape on a dark background. In Keynote, the animation differs slightly each time and appears to use some kind of physics, procedural generation or both.

> **Question:**
>
> How can I create a very similar type of animation in Xcode and Swift
>   code that is used in the Keynote "Vanish" animation below?

**Image:**

[image]